# Use zero based matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

Could the following equation be possible in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB)?

[image]

Suppose we have given data of length N, and we want to consider a linear equation among the some L nubmers and find coefficients a<sub>i</sub>. Is this possible? Because if yes, then coefficients can be solved by

```
a = pinv(D)*d
```

where D is a given matrix and d is a left vector.

The above equation comes from the following linear models

[image]

[image]

```
k = L, L+1, L+2, N-1
```

I have tested this code with some fixed f.

```
unction [a] = find_coeficient(y,N,L)
Lp = L + 1;
Np = N + 1;
d = y(L:N-1);
D=[];
for ii=Lp:(Np-1)
    % Index into the y vector for each row of D
    D = vertcat(D, y(ii:-1:(ii-Lp+1))');
end
a = D\d;
end
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely possible in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB). However, 0 indexes are not natively supported. You will need to do a "change of variables" by letting the index in each element be `index+1`. Here's a bit of an example:

```
% Generate some data
N = 40;
y = 10 * randn(N,1);
% Select an L value
L = N - 4 + 1;
d = y(L:N);
D = reshape(y,4,10);
% Solve the equation using the '\' rather than the pseudo inverse
b = D\d
```

For more information on the divide operator, see *[Systems of Linear Equations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/systems-of-linear-equations.html)*.

OK, I've thought through this a bit more. Part of the confusion here is the [change of variable limits](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cbruni/pdfs/Math101JanApr2012/Summations.pdf). The substitution applies to the indexing variable, **not** the size of the data, so `L` and `N` are unchanged, but the index is adjusted to keep it from falling off the edge of the array. So in the formula, just add 1 to every element index.

```
y[L] = [ y[L-1] y[L-2] ... y[0] ] * a1
.
.
y[N-1] = [ y[N-2] y[N-3] ... y[N-L-1] ] * aL
```

becomes:

```
y[L+1] = [ y[L-1+1] y[L-2+1] ... y[0+1] ] * a1
.
.
y[N-1+1] = [ y[N-2+1] y[N-3+1] ... y[N-L-1+1] ] * aL

=

y[L+1] = [ y[L] y[L-1] ... y[1] ] * a1
.
.
y[N] = [ y[N-1] y[N-2] ... y[N-L] ] * aL
```

Which we can then use to complete our script:

```
function a = find_coeficient(y,N,L)
  d = y((L+1):N);
  D=[];
  for ii=L:(N-1)
    % index into the y vector for each row of D
    D = vertcat(D, y(ii:-1:(ii-L+1))');
  end
  a = D\d;
end
```

Comment: i mean if i  enter L from keyboard,what should  be  reshape form?

Comment: but how can i access  elements of  y at N+1?

Comment: please see this link http://cant.ua.ac.be/sites/cant.ua.ac.be/files/courses/oe/MSThesis_satnam.pdf

Comment: i have  posted  and please check if it is correct according to thesis ,which i have posted

Comment: i see but how can i  create vector d?

Comment: thank very much,it helps me,but why it was not considered in thesis?

Comment: there is  part of this method and i will post and please help me ,it would be new   question